# In Rails 2, how would I define a callback method when adding models in a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback, has-many

In my project I have a Forum that has many Topics, and each Topic has many Posts. When I add a Post to a Topic, I would like to update a timestamp column in the Topic model to record when the last Post was added to the Topic. How can I do this?

Thank you for looking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the after_save callback in the model
=> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `after_create` callback in the `Post` model.

Comment: I've tried this, but the call back doesn't seems to run when a new Post is created. Maybe this has something to do with Post being a nested Resource?

Comment: Nevermind, my problem was that I wasn't saving the topic after I was timestamping it :x